# Cant establish Jsoup connection when passing URL String in a certain way

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, ssl, jsoup

i have a really strange problem.

I am running a spring application where i basicly just generate some threads and then try to establish a connection to a website to extract the status code of the response within those threads. Nothing special, but i have encountered a problem that really confuses me.

I have following code

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        Document document;
        Connection.Response response;
        String link = "https://lu.vpbank.com/htm/752/de_LU/Stellenangebote.htm";
        System.out.println(link);
        System.out.println(this.site.getLink());

        //Is working fine
        try {
            response = Jsoup.connect(link).followRedirects(false).ignoreHttpErrors(true).execute();
            System.out.println(response.statusCode());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Is not working
        try {
            response = Jsoup.connect(this.site.getLink()).followRedirects(false).ignoreHttpErrors(true).execute();
            System.out.println(response.statusCode());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The thing is the first attempt to create the connection is fine because i get declare the content of the string within the method.

On the second attempt i get the URL String from an object which i have created previousely and fetched the url from a database. This throws an error.....

The console output is:

```
https://lu.vpbank.com/htm/752/de_LU/Stellenangebote.htm
404
https://www.vpbank.lu/htm/752/de_LU/Stellenangebote.htm
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1680)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1054)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:754)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:713)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1623)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1528)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:736)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:297)
    at net.candidatis.tierone.crawls.careersite.CrawlableCareerBasic.run(CrawlableCareerBasic.java:48)
    at net.candidatis.tierone.controllers.TestController.testCrawl(TestController.java:32)
    at net.candidatis.tierone.TieroneApplication.run(TieroneApplication.java:36)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
    at net.candidatis.tierone.TieroneApplication.main(TieroneApplication.java:27)
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1051)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:82)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:400)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:981)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1434)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1038)
    ... 22 more
```

As we can see in the console output the url is identically.

site is just a simple object that i create before launching the threads.

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Site {
    private final String link;
}
```

Anyone any idea what might be the cause of this error ?

Answer (score 0):

> As we can see in the console output, the URL is identical.

But, they are not identical. They have different hostnames, which is why you're getting different behaviors:

> https://**lu.vpbank.com**/htm/752/de_LU/Stellenangebote.htm
> https://**www.vpbank.lu**/htm/752/de_LU/Stellenangebote.htm

In a browser, the second redirects to the first. I'm guessing it has a different TLS setup, or may be validating the connection differently (has some required headers?) and that's why you're getting the connection reset error. But, that's a different issue.

(As an aside, thank you for providing enough detail including printing the actual URL you're trying to visit - makes it easy to help with a fresh set of eyes!)

Comment: Wow how could i missed that. A fresh set of eyes indeed...... my view is already a tunnel. I will try to match the headers exactly to the ones in my browser. A different TLS setup hmm... i wll try to solve it with those informations. Much appreciated !

Comment: So it was not because of any headers. Is there a way i can tell Jsoup to use a TLS setup similiar to my browser ? Im not really sure how i can fix this error. I basicly want Jsoup to get the response of the redirect so i can have the status code 404. (this problme occurs on many sites )

Comment: I debugged a bit - at least for me, the SSL connection does handshake correctly. However the server is either closing the connection or holding it open indefinitely (timeout) when the HTTP/1.1 request is made. It seems to only support HTTP/2. Which seems a bit rude! For now you will need to use a different client, like OkHttp. (On Android, jsoup goes through Ok Http as it's the base implementation, but on desktops it will still use HttpURLConnection.